# yt-dlp で自分でファイル名を指定する方法 変数を使わない

Tags: コマンドプロンプト

提示のコンソール画面ですが参考サイト通りファイル名を変数以外でオリジナルで入力するとエラーになります。どうやって自分で指定したファイル名を利用出来るのでしょうか？変数での指定方法はわかりますがそうじゃない方法が知りたいです。

###### 調べたこと

参考サイト等の`yt-dlp ファイル名`等のキーワードで色々調べましたが記事がヒットしません

参考サイト：https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#output-template

```
>yt-dlp ytsearch:251+248 -o "test.%(ext)" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbb7CndNGWk&list=RDzCmdKyNYDTw&index=13
```

###### ERROR

```
Usage: yt-dlp [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]

yt-dlp: error: invalid default output template 'test.%(ext)': incomplete format
'list' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
'index' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
```

Comment: 参照先ページの記述では`%(ext)`は全て末尾に`s`が付いていて、例えば [Output template examples](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#output-template-examples) の最初では `"test video.%(ext)s"` となっているので、`"test.%(ext)s"` としてみると良いかもしれません。加えて4つ目と5つ目の例では @shindo-o-3 さん回答のように、URL自体も `"` で囲っているので、併せて指定してみてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

出力ファイル名の指定は [OUTPUT TEMPLATE](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#output-template) の段落に記載があり、変数 (テンプレート) を使用せず
適当な名前を指定するだけです。(推奨はされないようですが)

> The simplest usage of `-o` is not to set any template arguments when downloading a single file, like in `yt-dlp -o funny_video.flv "https://some/video"` (hard-coding file extension like this is not recommended and could break some post-processing).

表示されているエラーは別の理由で、shindo-o-3 さんの回答の通り URL をダブルクォートで括るか、単一の動画 URL を指定するなら不要なパラメータを削除すればよさそうです。
(例: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbb7CndNGWk`)

Answer (score 2):

コマンドプロント上で&記号は二つ以上のコマンドを連続して実行する場合に使用します。したがって、URL部分のlist部分とindex部分がコマンドとして認識されてます。URL部分をダブルクォーテーションで囲みエスケープさせることで実行できるかもしれません。

```
yt-dlp ytsearch:251+248 -o "test.%(ext)" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbb7CndNGWk&list=RDzCmdKyNYDTw&index=13"
```